# How stop the link of href from being highlighted?

Tags: html, css

I am setting an anchor tag for an image. It is highlighted and I want to remove the image from being highlighted. How to do this?

This is my anchor tag (some PHP in it):

```
<a style="outline:none;"  href="<? echo base_url();?>/friends/UploadPhoto"> 
  <img src="<?=$imgp ?>" name="b1" width="90" height="80" border="0"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better, do this in your CSS sheet:

```
img {
    border: none;
}
```

If you want to do it only for images inside *a* tags, you could also do

```
a img {
    border: none;
}
```